# Pandas filter using multiple conditions and ignore entries that contain duplicates of substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe derived from a massive list of market tickers from a crypto exchange.
The list includes ALL combos yet I only need the tickers that are vs USD stablecoins.

The 1st 15 entries of the original dataframe...

```
           Asset            Price
0   1INCHBTC      0.00009650     
1   1INCHBUSD     5.74340000     
2   1INCHUSDT     5.74050000     
3   AAVEBKRW      164167.00000000
4   AAVEBNB       0.77600000     
5   AAVEBTC       0.00615200     
6   AAVEBUSD      365.00200000   
7   AAVEDOWNUSDT  2.02505200     
8   AAVEETH       0.17212000     
9   AAVEUPUSDT    81.89500000    
10  AAVEUSDT      365.57600000   
11  ACMBTC        0.00018420     
12  ACMBUSD       10.91700000    
13  ACMUSDT       10.89500000    
14  ADAAUD        1.59600000
```

Now...there are many USD stablecoins, however not every ticker has a pair with one.
So I used the most popular ones in order to make sure every asset has at least one match.

```
df = df.loc[(df.Asset.str[-3:] == 'DAI')|
            (df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'USDT')|
            (df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'BUSD')|
            (df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'TUSD')]
```

The 1st 15 entries of the new but 'messy' dataframe...

```
           Asset         Price
0   1INCHBUSD     5.74340000  
1   1INCHUSDT     5.74050000  
2   AAVEBUSD      365.00200000
3   AAVEDOWNUSDT  2.02505200  
4   AAVEUPUSDT    81.89500000 
5   AAVEUSDT      365.57600000
6   ACMBUSD       10.91700000 
7   ACMUSDT       10.89500000 
8   ADABUSD       1.21439000  
9   ADADOWNUSDT   3.46482700  
10  ADATUSD       1.21284000  
11  ADAUPUSDT     76.12900000 
12  ADAUSDT       1.21394000  
13  AERGOBUSD     0.43012000  
14  AIONBUSD      0.07210000
```

How do i filter/merge entries in this dataframe so that it removes duplicates?
I also need the substring to be removed at the end, so I'm left with just the asset and the USD price.

It should look something like this...

```
           Asset         Price
0   1INCH         5.74340000  
2   AAVE          365.00200000
3   AAVEDOWN      2.02505200  
4   AAVEUP        81.89500000 
6   ACM           10.91700000 
8   ADA           1.21439000  
9   ADADOWN       3.46482700  
11  ADAUP         76.12900000 
13  AERGO         0.43012000  
14  AION          0.07210000
```

This is for a portfolio tracker.
Also if there is a better way to do this without the middle step I'm all ears.

Comment: How do you decide which `Price` to keep when dropping dupes? Like `1INCH` keeps `BUSD` over `USDT`

Comment: It doesn't really matter for this use case as it's for a portfolio tracker, and the prices are so close to each other...However it would be more accurate if it was averaged between them, but again not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your expected output, you want to remove duplicates but keep **first** item:

```
df.Asset = df.Asset.str.replace(r"(DAI|USDT|BUSD|TUSD)$", "")
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="Asset", keep="first")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Asset       Price
0      1INCH    5.743400
2       AAVE  365.002000
3   AAVEDOWN    2.025052
4     AAVEUP   81.895000
6        ACM   10.917000
8        ADA    1.214390
9    ADADOWN    3.464827
11     ADAUP   76.129000
13     AERGO    0.430120
14      AION    0.072100
```

---

EDIT: To group and average:

```
df.Asset = df.Asset.str.replace(r"(DAI|USDT|BUSD|TUSD)$", "")
df = df.groupby("Asset")["Price"].mean().reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Asset       Price
0     1INCH    5.741950
1      AAVE  365.289000
2  AAVEDOWN    2.025052
3    AAVEUP   81.895000
4       ACM   10.906000
5       ADA    1.213723
6   ADADOWN    3.464827
7     ADAUP   76.129000
8     AERGO    0.430120
9      AION    0.072100
```

Comment: BTW is it possible to average them instead of keeping just the 1st one? While it is not needed it is a more accurate representation of the price.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
con1 = df.Asset.str[-3:] == 'DAI'
con2 = df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'USDT'
con3 = df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'BUSD'
con4 = df.Asset.str[-4:] == 'TUSD'

df['new'] = np.select(['con1','con2','con3','con4'], 
                      ['DAI','USDT','BUSD','TUSD'])
out = df[con1 | con2 | con3 | con4].groupby('new').head(1)
```

or

```
df[con1 | con2 | con3 | con4].drop_duplicates('new')
```